# How many threads run event loop in nodejs

Tags: node.js, libuv

I am checking nodejs internal architecture and was curious about the event loop. So I cloned the node repo and modified the libuv code a little and added printf statements to understand the loop better. Then I build the code and ran an empty js file.

I added a printf statement before uv__io_poll function call

`printf("polling io with thread %d\n", tid);`

where tid is the thread id.

After running the program, I got the following output

```
polling io with thread 2242953
polling io with thread 2242949
polling io with thread 2242949
polling io with thread 2242949
```

Why there are 2 different thread ids?

Comment: Wouldn't the answer (at least partially) depend on the exact program you're running?

Comment: You can assume, I went to github, cloned the repo > Modified the code > ran make command > got an executable node file > ran that executable node on an empty js file

Comment: Apologies, I missed that you ran it on an empty file. In any case, you should consider that Node.js may use multiple threads for things like stdin/stdout/stderr and the actual JS file (even though it's empty).

Comment: It's same pattern after multiple retries. AFAIK, V8 uses multiple threads underneath but processing of things only works on a single thread i.e. main thread. If you are saying that threads are switched, that seems improbable to me because of the same pattern every time.

Comment: You're showing I/O threads, which doesn't include the "main thread". [This page](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-nodejs-performance-and-thread-pool-management-dd8ce558f51d) may provide some more insight on how Node.js uses threads for various tasks.

Comment: What do you think, which thread will execute [this](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/unix/core.c#L384) code? This is event loop code. I've added a printf [here](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/unix/core.c#L409)